# Labels with constrains added to ImageView with aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have an ImageView that are pinned to top, left and right. I want it to increase/decrease height after what device it is viewed on and therefore did not add a specific height or pin it to the bottom, but instead added aspect ratio.

Under the ImageView, I have two labels that will vary in height. One can be a maximum of 4 lines (OVERSKRIFT OVERSKRIFT...) and the other should not have a limit (Label).

I do however see a mistake in the constraints as the image suggests. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: can u click the red icon screenshot it to see conflicts

Comment: @Sh_Khan there is no red icon :/

Comment: red arrow on views outline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Remove the bottom most constraint and re add it

2- set content Hugging priority vertical to overskirt label to 1000

Comment: set also compression resistance to 1000 vertical

Comment: Just messes with all the other constraints

Comment: send me that xib and I ' will look at

Answer (score 0):

1. ImageView - Top,left,right and AspectRatio [Tick the Constraints to margin]
2. Label1 - Top,left,right and height and NumberOfLines is 0
3. Label2 - Top,left,right and height and NumberOfLines is 0

Click, `UILabel`, in `Size Inspector`, Give `horizontal` and `vertical` as `1000` & `1000` respectively for both `Content Hugging Property` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority`.

Click, `UILabel's Height` Constraints, in Size Inspector, Change its `Priority` to `750`.